# Inaccessible base in C++

Tags: c++, object

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// pure virtual function remake 

class studenttemplate
{
    public:
    virtual void studentname()=0;
};

class studentone:studenttemplate
{
    public:
    void studentname()
    {
        cout<<"my name is student one and im in college "<<endl;
    }
};

class studenttwo:studentone
{
    public:
    void studentname()
    {
        cout<<"my name is student two and im in college "<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    studenttemplate *n;
    *n = studentone();
    n->studentname();
    
    n = new studenttwo();
    
    n->studentname();
    
    return 0;
}
```

I recently started to learn object-orientated programming, and I'm on the topic of polymorphism and pure virtual functions. I made my own example, but for some reason the error message states that 'studenttemplate' is an inaccessible base of 'studenttwo' and 'studenttemplate' is an inaccessible base of 'studentone'.

I don't understand what I did wrong; student template should be the base class.

Comment: I added the proper tags around the code. You'll want to fix the rest.

Comment: What does your textbook say about `public` vs `private` inheritance?

Comment: `studenttemplate *n; *n = studentone();` is derefencing an uninitialized pointer, you need to either 1) use `new`, eg: `studenttemplate *n = new studentone(); ... delete n;` or 2) create the object locally and then point at it, eg: `studentone one; studenttemplate *n = &one;`

Comment: Inheritance of classes is `private` by default.  For bases to be accessible from arbitrary code, inheritance needs to be `public`.  For example, `class studentone:  public studenttemplate ...`.

Answer (score 4):

A declaration like this:

```
class studenttwo : studentone
```

Gives you *private inheritance*, such that other classes aren't allowed to see that `studenttwo` is a subclass of `studentone`.

You probably want to use *public inheritance* instead, like this:

```
class studenttwo : public studentone
```